# How can I find duplicate consecutive values in this table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table which I query like so:

```
select date, value from mytable order by date
```

and this gives me results:

```
date                  value
02/26/2009 14:03:39   1                
02/26/2009 14:10:52   2          (a)
02/26/2009 14:27:49   2          (b)
02/26/2009 14:34:33   3
02/26/2009 14:48:29   2          (c)
02/26/2009 14:55:17   3
02/26/2009 14:59:28   4
```

I'm interested in the rows of this result set where the value is the same as the one in the previous or next row, like row b which has `value=2` the same as row (a).  I don't care about rows like row (c) which has `value=2` but does not come directly after a row with `value=2`.  How can I query the table to give me all rows like (a) and (b) only?  This is on Oracle, if it matters.

Comment: Are there any other fields in the table, for example a sequential primary key?  That would make it easier!  Is it a transaction table, or might records be deleted (i.e. to do joins and tests with id-1 or id+1)?

Comment: @Kieren yes there's a primary key, but they are handed out in an order inconsistent with the date field.  I'm not sure what you intend about "joins and tests" but yes, records get removed and replaced quite often.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the lead and lag analytic functions.

```
create table t3 (d number, v number);
insert into t3(d, v) values(1, 1);
insert into t3(d, v) values(2, 2);
insert into t3(d, v) values(3, 2);
insert into t3(d, v) values(4, 3);
insert into t3(d, v) values(5, 2);
insert into t3(d, v) values(6, 3);
insert into t3(d, v) values(7, 4);

select d, v, case when v in (prev, next) then '*' end match, prev, next from (
  select
    d,
    v,
    lag(v, 1) over (order by d) prev,
    lead(v, 1) over (order by d) next
  from
    t3
)
order by
  d
;
```

Matching neighbours are marked with * in the match column,

[image]

Comment: Why do you have **order by d** when the data is already ordered by **d** per your inserts? Also, the original problem didn't appear to require sorting to execute properly.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simplified version of @Bob Jarvis' answer, the main difference being the use of just one subquery instead of four,

```
with f as (select row_number() over(order by d) rn, d, v from t3)
select
  a.d, a.v,
  case when a.v in (prev.v, next.v) then '*' end match
from
  f a
    left join
  f prev
    on a.rn = prev.rn + 1
    left join
  f next
    on a.rn = next.rn - 1
order by a.d
;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Janek Bogucki has pointed out LEAD and LAG are probably the easiest way to accomplish this - but just for fun let's try to do it by using only basic join operations:

```
SELECT mydate, VALUE FROM
  (SELECT a.mydate, a.value,
          CASE WHEN a.value = b.value THEN '*' ELSE NULL END AS flag1,
          CASE WHEN a.value = c.value THEN '*' ELSE NULL END AS flag2
     FROM
       (SELECT ROWNUM AS outer_rownum, mydate, VALUE
         FROM mytable
         ORDER BY mydate) a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (select ROWNUM-1 AS inner_rownum, mydate, VALUE
         from mytable
         order by myDATE) b
       ON b.inner_rownum = a.outer_rownum
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (select ROWNUM+1 AS inner_rownum, mydate, VALUE
         from mytable
         order by myDATE) c
       ON c.inner_rownum = a.outer_rownum
     ORDER BY a.mydate)
  WHERE flag1 = '*' OR
        flag2 = '*';
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: rownum is assigned before the results are sorted so this is not guaranteed to work. This shows how row_number() can be used instead (to get an ascending sequence of numbers that matches the order by clause):

select rownum, row_number() over(order by v-d) from t3 order by v-d;

This uses the data from my answer above.