# SQL query to choose row before two consecutive true values

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

Here is my table.

```
Price   Volume
------------------
60          0
70          10
80          0
90          0
100         40
200         40
300         40
400         0
500         50
600         60
```

It is ordered by Price.

I need to choose all rows before two consecutive zeros in Volume column. So the result should look like

```
Price   Volume
------------------
100         40
200         40
300         40
400         0
500         50
600         60
```

I really do not know where to start with this type of query. I could only think go pulling data into C# and the loading back into table.

Regards,

Comment: which DBMS are you using? DBs are not well suited to do this type of thing, but there are options.

Comment: Doing this thing in C# once you get the data isn't an option?

Comment: Your example result is actually all rows **after** two consecutive zeros, not *before*.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL:

```
with flagged as (
  select price, 
         volume,
         case 
           when volume + lag(volume) over (order by price) = 0 then 1
           else 0
         end as rn
  from prices
), counted as (
  select price, 
         volume, 
         sum(rn) over (order by price) as cn,
         rn
  from flagged
)
select price, volume
from counted
where cn > 0 and rn = 0
order by price
```

Here is a SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2434/4

Comment: Excellent solution! Also great example of LAG usage. At the very end I don't think you need "volume > 0". You will miss value price  = 400 and volume = 0. Do you know how time efficient usage of LAG or LEAD?

Comment: @user1700890: I changed the `volume = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL cannot handle this. You need a cursor to cycle through the ordered rows and decide what to output, which requires the use of some variables.

Depending on the RDBMS you are using, you could write a stored procedure that reads the rows and filters them. Otherwise you must have the application do the filtering.

Comment: I guess I will end up doing it in C#. I just want to make sure that LEAD and LAG would not work here.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298526/how-can-i-find-duplicate-consecutive-values-in-this-table)

Comment: You want to make sure that it doesn't work? Why is that?

Comment: Standard SQL *can* handle this.

Comment: @fancyPants. Before I start writing C# code, I want to make sure that I tried everything in SQL. I poorly worded it: if LEAD and LAG work, I do not need to write C# code.

Comment: Since when di LAG and LEAD make it into standard ANSI SQL? Anyway they are available in MS SQL Server, so go for it.

Comment: `lead()` and `lag()` made it into the standard about 11 years ago when SQL:2003 was introduced. And e.g. Oracle was able to do that for nearly 20 years

Answer (score 0):

In sql server 2012+ you can do this with a couple [LAG](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) statements.

Lag for the 2 previous values and where when they are both 0.