# How to select sequential duplicates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I would like to select duplicate entries from a SQL Server table, *but only if the id is consecutive.*

I have been trying to twist [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3298645/1778169) to my needs, but I can't get it to work.

The above answer is for Oracle, but I see that SQL Server also has `lead` and `lag` functions.

Also, I think that the answer above puts a `*` next to duplicates, but I only want to select the duplicates.

```
select 
    id, companyName, 
    case 
       when companyName in (prev, next) 
          then '*' 
    end match, 
    prev, 
    next 
from 
    (select
         id,
         companyName,
         lag(companyName, 1) over (order by id) prev,
         lead(companyName, 1) over (order by id) next
     from
         companies)
order by
    id;
```

**Example**:

So from this data set:

```
id      companyName
-------------------    
1       dogs ltd
2       cats ltd
3       pigs ltd
4       pigs ltd
5       cats ltd
6       cats ltd
7       dogs ltd
8       pigs ltd
```

I want to select:

```
id      companyName
-------------------    
3       pigs ltd
4       pigs ltd
5       cats ltd
6       cats ltd
```

### Update

Every now and again I am taken aback by the quantity and quality of answers I get on SO. This is one of those times. I don't have the level of expertise to judge one answer as being better than another, so I've gone for SqlZim as this was the first working answer I saw. But it's great to see the different approaches. Especially when only an hour ago I was wondering "is this even possible?".

Comment: What about gaps between `id` but without rows between them?

Comment: Good point. Just directly consecutive ids in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands style problem, but instead of using two `row_numbers()`, we use the `id` and `row_number()` in the innermost subquery. Followed by `count() over()` to get the count per `grp`, and finally return those with a `cnt > 1`.

```
select id, companyname 
from (
  select 
      id
    , companyName
    , grp
    , cnt = count(*) over (partition by companyname, grp)
  from (
    select *
      , grp = id - row_number() over (partition by companyname order by id)
    from
      companies
    ) islands
  ) d
where cnt  > 1
order by id
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ACP73683

returns:

```
+----+-------------+
| id | companyname |
+----+-------------+
|  3 | pigs ltd    |
|  4 | pigs ltd    |
|  5 | cats ltd    |
|  6 | cats ltd    |
+----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 5):

You are very close to what you want:

```
select id, companyName
from (select c.*,
             lag(companyName, 1) over (order by id) prev,
             lead(companyName, 1) over (order by id) next
      from companies c
     ) a
where CompanyName in (prev, next)
order by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the WHERE clause you just need to limit to those where the companyName is the same as the prev or the next

```
select id, companyName
from (
   select id, companyName,
   lag(companyName, 1) over (order by id) as prev,
   lead(companyName, 1) over (order by id) as next
   from companies
 ) q
 where companyName in (prev, next)
 order by id;
```

To make sure the id's are really without gaps then you can do it like this:

```
select id, companyName
from (
   select id, companyName,
   lag(concat(id+1,companyName), 1) over (order by id) as prev,
   lead(concat(id-1,companyName), 1) over (order by id) as next
   from companies
 ) q
 where concat(id,companyName) in (prev, next)
 order by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

One more alternate form, using LEAD() and LAG() (SQL 2012 and up)

```
SELECT id, CompanyName
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LEAD(CompanyName, 1) OVER(ORDER BY id) as nc,
        LAG(CompanyName, 1) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS pc
    FROM #t t
    ) x
WHERE nc = companyName
    OR pc = companyName
```

Here is the test data, so you can check it out yourself.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (id int not null PRIMARY KEY, companyName varchar(16) not null)

INSERT INTO #t Values 
(1,       'dogs ltd'),
(2,       'cats ltd'),
(3,       'pigs ltd'),
(4,       'pigs ltd'),
(5,       'cats ltd'),
(6,       'cats ltd'),
(7,       'dogs ltd'),
(8,       'pigs ltd')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Row_Number() and get the duplicates based on partition by clause

```
;with cte as (
SELECT id, companyName,
    RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by id order by companynae) from #yourTable
    )
    Select * from cte where RowN > 1
```

Can you provide your input and expected output to verify this query

Comment: Thanks Kannan. Should this pull the dataset example I have above?  I'm not getting any rows on the target table when I try this.  I'm going to set up a simpler table to test it.