# Select only unique, sequential rows in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There have been a couple of previous questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217394/how-to-select-sequential-duplicates-in-sql-server?noredirect=1&lq=1) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3298645/1778169)) that are quite close to what I'm trying to do, but haven't been able to tease the answer out.

In my case, I have data that may contain multiple sequential duplicates, so starting from where [Martin did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217394/how-to-select-sequential-duplicates-in-sql-server?noredirect=1&lq=1):

e.g.

```
id      companyName
-------------------    
1       dogs ltd
2       cats ltd
3       pigs ltd
4       pigs ltd
5       pigs ltd
6       cats ltd
7       cats ltd
8       dogs ltd
9       pigs ltd
```

I want to return

```
companyName
-----------    
dogs ltd
cats ltd
pigs ltd
cats ltd
dogs ltd
pigs ltd
```

eliminating the **sequential** duplicates, but keeping the unique values in order. In all the previous questions, using the *lead* and *lag* functions, that would only look one ahead or behind, not allowing for 3 or more duplicated sequential values.

Comment: 'distinct' would not duplicate 'dogs ltd' and 'pigs ltd' appropriately

Comment: OK Gottcha! Yes, I missed the non-sequential dups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT companyName
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id
            , companyName
            , LEAD(companyName, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY id) lead
        FROM yourTable
    ) Q
WHERE
    companyName <> lead
    OR lead IS NULL
ORDER BY id
```